# Xpages Link Open New Browser Tab

Tags: xpages

I have found a few similar questions to this in stackoverflow but nothing exactly matches.  I am attempting to amend an `Xpages` project where the search results are shown in a Dynamic View Panel.  The first column of the search results is a link that opens the record in the same page.  What I want to do is have this link open the record in a seperate page.  It is the `"Dynamic"` part of the view that is confusing I think as there is no `"Column Name"` or `"Column View"` to add in a window.open or a `target="_blank"` that I can see.  How would I go about this please?

The relevant section of the XPage only has the following;

```
<xp:panel id="maincontentpanel">
    <xe:dynamicViewPanel rows="30" id="dynamicViewPanel1" width="100%">
      <xe:this.data>
         <xp:dominoView viewName="(keywordsUser)" var="view">
         </xp:dominoView>
      </xe:this.data>
   </xe:dynamicViewPanel>
</xp:panel>
```

When viewing the source in HTML the clickable column shows the following;

```
<tr>
    <td class="xspColumnViewStart">
        <a id="view:_id1:cc4cconeuilayout:OneUIMainAreaCallback:dynamicViewPanel1:0:_id6:_internalColumnLink"
           href="*routetoourrecord*";action=editDocument"
           class="xspLinkViewColumn">2014</a>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic View Panel has a property "target" in All Properties where you can select "_blank". This should add the attribute `target="_blank"` to the links in first column. But, unfortunately, this works in *Notes client only*.

So, there is no property we just can set. Luckily, rendered links have an own class "xspLinkViewColumn" (see your source HTML example). With `dojo.query` we can get all elements with this class and add the target attribute on client side.

Just add following event code to your XPage:

```xml
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onClientLoad"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
         dojo.query(".xspLinkViewColumn").attr("target", "_blank");
    ]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

All links will get the attribute `target="_blank"` this way and documents will be opened in a new browser tab.

Comment: Forgive me as I am still quite new to XPages.  Is the "view column links" you mentioned a property of the Dynamic View Panel?  If so I can't see it!

Comment: I updated my answer and hope it's better to understand. You really just have to add the code above to your Xpage or custom control and it will work.

Comment: Thanks again Knut. I added the code you provided into the XPage but it still isn't opening the record in a new browser tab\window. I tried adding the code within the XML tag for the dynamicviewpanel, then performed a build and clean but no difference. Then moved the code outside the dynamicviewpanel to near the top of the Xpage - again build and clean but still the same. I then tried removing the code and in the XPage's properties, in the "onClientLoad" event I added the following, dojo.query(".xspLinkViewColumn").attr("target", "_blank"); but still didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your last two ways to include the code are right and should work. Please test if code gets execute adding this alert: `alert(dojo.query(".xspLinkViewColumn").length);`

Comment: Wait!!!  It is working.  I did another clean but this made sure it included cleaning the On-Disk AD part of project (so it works with SVN) and I also cleared the browser cache and its working.  Thank you so much Knut.  You have been very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Just to let know the code does not to work with the Bootstrap theme.

Instead you can use

```
dojo.query('[id$="_internalColumnLink"]').attr("target", "_blank");
```